# Who said "You are nothing but a boy, trying to prove himself a man" in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification

At 0:14 in the video below, there's a voice saying:

> You are nothing but a boy, trying to prove himself a man.

I want to know who said this and in which context?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Laufey says it to Thor in the first *Thor* movie when Thor goes to Jotunheim to seek why they attacked Asgard. Laufey is calling Thor out on his intentions for going there in the first place stating that it isn't to protect the Nine Realms or seek justice but just to pick a fight and look like a man.

> **Thor:** Not when you'd use it to make war against other Realms.
>
> **Laufey:** And why have you come here? To make peace? You long for battle. You crave it. I see you for what you are, Thor Odinson. Nothing but a boy, trying to prove himself a man.
>
> **Thor:** This boy has grown tired of your mockery.
>
> <sub>*Thor*</sub>

Comment: Where is your quote from? Script, novelization, rewatching movie clip a few dozen times? Because it doesn't seem to agree with other people's versions.

Comment: @Martha It's from [IMSDb](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Thor.html), the same as the one in the answer by HorusKol and it agrees with that answer too unless I'm missing something.

Comment: This line is better than the one he says in the movie.

Answer (score 15):

The quote is from [Laufey](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Laufey), made in [the first *Thor* movie](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/thor/quotes/):

> **Laufey:** Your father is a murderer and a thief! And why have you come here? To make peace? You long for battle. You crave it! You're nothing but a boy trying to prove himself a man.

Happens around 2:30 [in this YouTube clip](https://youtu.be/IQT-c9pnPvA?t=146) (video has embedding disabled).

Answer (score 8):

That line was [said by Laufey](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Thor.html), king of the Ice Giants on Jotunheim, when Thor goes to pick a fight against Odin's orders.

> And why have you come here? To make peace? You long for battle. You crave it. I see you for what you are, Thor Odinson. Nothing but a boy, trying to prove himself a man.